# Is there a way to transpose a column into rows with each row having the first value from the previous row deleted and a new tail value inserted?

Tags: python, excel, postgresql

Is there a way to transpose a column into rows with each row having the first value from the previous row deleted and a new tail value inserted such that the second value(value in second column in that row) from the previous row becomes first value(value in the  first column in that row) in the next row. The resulting table has values in a sliding window fashion as they move from row to row until they are popped out of the table. I have used the Index function in Excel but it is tiresome as i have to update it for each new row and I have around 2000 rows to create. Thanks
[What I have done so far in the Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDE3X.png)
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A1)*22-12+COLUMN(A1))
I have to update the number 22 for each new row up until 2000 and flash fill the rows manually.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?  There may be a better way.

Comment: I am trying to create a dataset of measured solar production values at every 15 minutes in a sliding window fashion with the first column as the target column for a machine learning learning model and the preceding values as features e.g for 1245hrs the values at 1230, 1215 etc will be the features and at 1230 the values at 1215 1200 will be the features.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it in postgres, or e.g. pandas? In pandas, you could do sth like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(10)})  # a is your original data-series

for shift in range(1,df.shape[0]):
    df[shift] = df['a'].shift(-shift)

print(df)

   a    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
1  1  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN
2  2  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
3  3  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  4  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  5  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN 
6  6  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
....
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much. What about in postgres if you do not mind me asking?